# Email Redirect to Database setting for civicrm-settings.php?

Tags: civimail

ola, i just stumbled upon the https://github.com/ixiam/com.ixiam.modules.mailreader extension and would love to use it on our dev/stage environment.

It enables a ui to read email that were redirected to the database. now my question is: is it possible to enable DB email redirect with a line of code in civicrm.settings.php?

When copying production databases to dev & stage it would be great to be able to override the mail setting to redirect to the database.

So far I only found 
define('CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG', 1); and 
define('CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG', '/dev/null');
as available settings in https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/

Answer (score 7):

Yes its possible to set Outbound email to 'Redirect to Database' by simply adding 2 lines in your civicrm.settings.php

```
global $civicrm_setting;
$civicrm_setting['Mailing Preferences']['mailing_backend']['outBound_option'] = 5;
```

**Note:** If `global $civicrm_setting;` is already present then no need to add it.

Comment: Richard, Did the setting work?

Answer (score 1):

$civicrm_setting['Mailing Preferences']['mailing_backend']['outBound_option'] = 5;

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It would be helpful to others if you could edit it to provide a bit more detail.